# Add image to python script?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've got a wxPython app that uses the following line before creating a wx.BitmapButton:

```
imagePlus = wx.Image('wxPlus.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
```

Is there a way to include the image's data in the image, and so something more like this?

```
plusData = '...√#,›o~ño\Ä¶˚ﬂy™Ω.…Õo)Ú∞L∂W_≤Ï~˛⁄...'
imagePlus = wx.Image(plusData, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
```

Comment: Could you clarify "Is there a way to include the image's data in the image" please? At a guess I would say you want `imagePlus = open('wxPlus.png')` (or, better, `with open('wxPlus.png') as imagePlus:`)

Comment: No, I want to use `x = wx.Image()` with data stored in a variable (as in `with open() as x`) instead of a file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the module StringIO you can create a 'file-like object' that you can pass to wx.ImageFromStream.

```
import StringIO

stream = StringIO.StringIO()
stream.write('...√#,›o~ño\Ä¶˚ﬂy™Ω.…Õo)Ú∞L∂W_≤Ï~˛⁄...')

image = wx.ImageFromStream(stream)
```

Comment: No. wx.Image(...) requires a path, not an IO object. http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#__init__

Comment: 1. http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wximage.html#wximage - wx.Image can take an InputStream as an argument but maybe not in wxPython. However: 
2. I used wx.ImageFromStream - http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#ImageFromStream

Answer (score 1):

If you're using wxPython, I think [img2py](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.tools.img2py-module.html) would be worth a look.